# How to update React component from a separate component

Tags: reactjs, components, use-state

I have 3 components

One component is map with a layer of points on it

Component #2 is a list of all the points on the map and appears next to the map

Component #3 is a form that lets the user filter the map.

I would like for the submitting the form to filter the map. i would also like for clicking on a point in the map to filter or update the accompanying list.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this with React, specifically with React states if states can only be update from the same component:

Main file has:

```
import Form from '/myForm';
import MyMap from '/myMap';
import data from 'data.json';

 return (
    <div>
        <MyForm/>
        <MyMap data={data} />
    </div>

 )
```

Form Component #3:

```
import MyMap from '/myMap';
import MapList from '/mapList';

const Form = ({ data}) => {
     React.useEffect(() => { 

         mapForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){

           ..somehow update MyMap state to filter map points and somehow update data/state in <mapList />

         })

      }, []);
     return (
        <form id="MyForm" name="mapForm">
          ..form elements...
          <input className="buttons" type="submit" value="Submit"  id="mapSubmit"/>
        </form>
      
     );
}
```

MapList component #2:

```
...Loop through data and return <li>

const MapList = ({ data}) => {
   const [mapDataList, updateList] = useState(data);

    const items = data.map((item) => {
      return (
        <li>{item.name}</li>
      );
    });

     return (

        <div>
          <div id="map-items">
            <ul>
                {items}
                
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Map Component #1

```
import MapList from '/mapList'
import React, {useState } from 'react';


const MyMap = ({ data}) => {
    const [mapDataPoints, updatePoints] = useState(data);


     mapPoints.on('click',function (e) {
        ..somehow update data/state in <mapList /> ...
     }

     return (
        <div>
            <mapList data={mapDataPoints} />
            <div> map goes here with points layer </div>
         
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: You can keep track of your state at the top level of your app, pass in relevant data and functions to update that data as props to your child components. In this particular example, your top level parent component can contain state to track all of the data points on the map. Component 1 and 2 both receive this data as a prop from the parent component. Component 3, your form, receives a function as a prop to edit/filter the data points.

Comment: Thank you. I get an `Error in function renderWithHooks` when I test it, but will keep trying. Do I write the function in the parent component like a normal function `function myFunction(){}` or as a constructor?

Comment: You can write it like a normal function, yes. Feel free to update with what you've tried so far